# Javascript: website header slideshow fade-in effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, slideshow

Since this is one rather long question-thank in advance to those who bother to read it! I am doing a personal blog website project, and in the index page, I want to achieve a slideshow header (contains a background picture, a title and a button redirecting user to the actual psot) to display featured blog posts dynamically. I also wanted fade-in effect when the header transform into another one. My html for the header looks like this:

```js
var slideIndex = 0;

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("header-slide");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.opacity = 0;
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.opacity = 1;
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 3000);
}
```

```css
.header-1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29), #000), url(background-image#1);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header-2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29), #000), url(background-image#2);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header-3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29), #000), url(background-image#3);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header-style {
  display: none;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="header-slide">
    <header class="header-1">
      <nav>
        <div class="row">
          <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><a href="article_directory.html">Articles</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://collegiatecycling.org/accc/">Collegiate Racing</a></li>
            <li><a href="photo_gallery.html">Multimedia</a></li>
            <li><a href="current_projects.html">Current Porjects</a></li>
            <li><a href="get_in_touch.php">Get in touch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#first-footer-child">External</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="hero-text-box">
        <h1>Article#1</h1>
        <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">Read full story</a>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>

  <div class="header-slide">
    <header class="header-2">
      <nav>
        <div class="row">
          <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><a href="article_directory.html">Articles</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://collegiatecycling.org/accc/">Collegiate Racing</a></li>
            <li><a href="photo_gallery.html">Multimedia</a></li>
            <li><a href="current_projects.html">Current Porjects</a></li>
            <li><a href="get_in_touch.php">Get in touch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#first-footer-child">External</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="hero-text-box">
        <h1>Article#2</h1>
        <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>

  <div class="header-slide">
    <header class="header-3">
      <nav>
        <div class="row">
          <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><a href="article_directory.html">Articles</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://collegiatecycling.org/accc/">Collegiate Racing</a></li>
            <li><a href="photo_gallery.html">Multimedia</a></li>
            <li><a href="current_projects.html">Current Porjects</a></li>
            <li><a href="get_in_touch.php">Get in touch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#first-footer-child">External</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="hero-text-box">
        <h1>Article#3</h1>
        <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

I already have the following js script, which, while embedded in the html file, does slideshow the header, but fails to achieve a fade-in effect.

I want the fade-in effect as well, so I added the following CSS codes.

With all the above measures, my website header still fails to slideshow in with fade-in effect. My question is, it seems setting the transition property doesn't change anything, as the header opacity is changed by my js script (so every time it changes from 0 to 1, the CSS would handle how it changes)? Any assistance appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using css keyframe animation:

```css
#header {
  animation: fade 5s ease-out infinite;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
     opacity: .1
  }
  100% {
     opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
<img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4016/4543539771_1325623dd6.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

Or have a look at the browser native animation api:

> The Web Animations API opens the browser’s animation engine to
>   developers and manipulation by JavaScript.
>
> This API was designed to underlie implementations of both CSS
>   Animations and CSS Transitions, and leaves the door open to future
>   animation effects.
>
> It is one of the most performant ways to animate on the Web where
>   supported, letting the browser make its own internal optimizations
>   without hacks

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53785137/2494754

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that solves the problem and gives a very nice fade-in effect as long as the js time interval is greater than that of CSS.